# GitLabRunner SSH exector doesn't read full $PATH

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

When using ssh to login to the server from inside the the docker container and using echo $PATH it get

```
/home/daniel/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/daniel/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

When using

```
install:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo ${PATH}
```

NVM,SDK and other installed tools are missing

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Using source .profile, .bashrc or /etc/profile doesn't work